# How to make JAX-WS use https for soap:address / schemaLocation

Tags: java, scala, wsdl, jax-ws, haproxy

I'm using Scala + JAX-WS to build a simple SOAP server, but have run into issues with the auto generated locations in the WSDL. The service is published like this:

```
val endpoint = Endpoint(new MySoapServer())
endpoint.publish("http://10.2.2.100")
```

Which creates the following elements in the WSDL

```
<service name="MyService">
  <port name="MyPort" binding="tns:MyPortBinding">
    <soap:address location="http://10.2.2.100"/>
  </port>
</service>
```

and

```
<xsd:schema>
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://10.2.2.100/?xsd=1"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

However, the server sits behind a proxy that only accepts https requests, so those urls are useless...

How can I modify both the `schemaLocation` and `soap:address location` elements, so that they read `https://10.2.2.100`?

I've tried using `X-Forwarded-Proto`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004067/change-schemalocation-and-soapaddress-location-in-runtime-generated-wsdl-with-j), but still no luck...

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here: can you not just change the address string in your published endpoint to create the desired address? Or generate a wsdl, hand-correct the address and then either refer to that wsdl in your `MySoapServer` or give the doctored wsdl to your client

Comment: I can't change the string; the endpoint only handles http protocol. The second suggestion would work, but then I'd end up having to maintain a SOAP service that's both object- and contract-first (kinda). Currently, I'm thinking the best thing to do is bit the bullet and make the move to a contract-first service using a hand-written wsdl, scalaxb, and spray...