# Setting the endpoint of JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean at runtime

Tags: java, web-services, spring, endpoint

I'm using JAX-WS and Spring to create a webservice client from a given WSDL. The JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean is quite easy to configure if you have the WSDL and know the enpoint address up front. But now I want to set the enpoint address dynamically at runtime because it isn't know at the startup of the application. Does anybody know if and how this can be done with the JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2490895/116509

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I can cast my service to BindingProvider and then set the value for ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY. It only seems a bit clumsy for such a common situation.