# overriding endpoint address in the JAX-WS WSDL throw InaccessibleWSDLException

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws

I am facing an issue when trying to init a simple Jax-ws webservice, 

the exception is thrown when I init the new service object: [e.g. new HelloService()]

I was trying to follow instructions on java.net on  how to [override endpoint address](https://metro.java.net/nonav/1.2/guide/How_to_invoke_and_endpoint_by_overriding_endpoint_address_in_the_WSDL.html)

I also found similar question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490737/how-to-change-webservice-url-endpoint/2490895#2490895), 

 but still facing the same issue:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.InaccessibleWSDLException: 2 counts of InaccessibleWSDLException.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://server-ps:8080/halloWorld/HalloWorldWebService.wsdl
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://server-ps:8080/halloWorld/HalloWorldWebService.wsdl?wsdl
```

Here is the code I am using (from the java.net article)

```
String halloServiceUrl = "http://server-ps:8080/halloWorld/HalloWorldWebService?wsdl";
HelloService service = new HelloService(); // I get the exception here..
HelloPort proxy =  service.getHelloPort(); 
    ((BindingProvider)proxy).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,alloServiceUrl);
proxy.sayHello("Hello World!");
```

full stack Trace:

```
  com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.InaccessibleWSDLException: 2 counts of InaccessibleWSDLException.

 java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://server-ps:8080/halloWorld/HalloWorldWebService.wsdl
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://server-ps:8080/halloWorld/HalloWorldWebService.wsdl?wsdl

 at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:161)
 at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:133)
 at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:254)
 at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:217)
 at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:165)
 at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:93)
 at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
 at halloWorld.services.HalloWorldWebService_v1.HalloWorldWebService.<init>(HalloWorldWebService.java:46)
 at com.starOne.ps.cmmg.pkg.test.MiscTest.testhalloWorldServiceCall(MiscTest.java:73)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: are you able to view the wsdl in the browser ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to work it out.

Previously the command I used to generate the clients was:

```
wsimport -keep halloWorldWebService.wsdl -d output -s output -verbose
```

Once I added wsdllocation parameter to wsimport:

```
-wsdllocation http://localhost:8088/mockHWebServiceSOAP?WSDL
```

It is working as expected using the code:

```
String halloServiceUrl = "http://server-ps:8080/halloWorld/HalloWorldWebService";
HelloService service = new HelloService(); 
HelloPort proxy =  service.getHelloPort(); 
((BindingProvider)proxy).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,alloServiceUrl);
proxy.sayHello("Hello World!");
```

Thank you!