# Purpose of BindingProvider in JAX-WS web service

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I have searched a lot to find the concrete explanation of `BindingProvider` used in web services but I could get the complete information.

I have also read official documentation but I am still confused about the concept behind the `BindingProvider`. The official doc says

> **4.2 javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider**
>
> The BindingProvider interface represents a component that provides a
>   protocol binding for use by clients, it is implemented by proxies and
>   is extended by the Dispatch interface.

In docs, what is mean by Protocol Binding?

Can you guys please help me in understanding What is `BindingProvider` and its purpose with the help of simple code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `BindingProvider` interface defines accessor methods for the request and response context maps. The `Dispatch<T>` interface extends the `javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider` interface. Standard `BindingProvider` properties are defined by the JAX-WS specification and the client program may set and get these properties. The application may also define application-specific properties, but the specification discourages this for portability reasons.

See Also:

- [Interface BindingProvider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/BindingProvider.html)
- [JAX-WS 2.2 API](https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.2.6/docs/ch03.html)

Example:

- [How to change webservice url endpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490737/how-to-change-webservice-url-endpoint)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Aleksey. If I say that BindingProvider object is a client side object (by client side, I mean web service client) with which we can retrieve request and response context and can perform some other related client side activities. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help Aleksey.