# Select between two webservices

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

it is possible to decide one or another webservice by a condition into a Phase?
I have 2 ws: ws1 and ws2.
I want to decide to call ws1 or ws2 depending of a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as long as the client/web service contracts/schema's are the same. Just replace the URI with corresponding the ws1/ws2 endpoint.

Comment: but can I decide in my invoke() method of the Handler?

Comment: If the boolean parameter you are getting from the client comes up through a client request then yes it would be in the invoke (HandleRequest) from there you will need to modify the web service binding. Those classes are available in both C# and Java, I am not sure what language you are writing your web service in.

Comment: i am using Java and axis2 1.5.6

Comment: Check out some of the comments on this post.  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490737/how-to-change-webservice-url-endpoint