# Java SOAP client very slow

Tags: wsdl, jax-ws

I am building a client for a web service. I didn't want to the client downloading the wsdl everytime and got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2490895/2711378) answer.

But evaluating the source files of `WSServiceDelegate`,

```
URL url = wsdl.getSystemId()==null ? null : JAXWSUtils.getEncodedURL(wsdl.getSystemId());
WSDLModel model = parseWSDL(url, wsdl, serviceClass);                                    
service = model.getService(this.serviceName);                                            
if (service == null)                                                                     
    throw new WebServiceException(                                                       
        ClientMessages.INVALID_SERVICE_NAME(this.serviceName,                            
            buildNameList(model.getServices().keySet())));                               
// fill in statically known ports                                                        
for (WSDLPort port : service.getPorts())                                                 
    ports.put(port.getName(), new PortInfo(this, port));
```

I see that it still parses the wsdl to get the service. How can I get around that. I provided the endpoint url using the context.

I need the client to be as fast and as small as possible, adding a huge wsdl in there is worst than downloading the wsdl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the operations you are interested in, you can build your own SOAP messages based on the wsdl's Request/Response messages and the xsd. You can use Jaxb tools to convert from XSD to Java classes. You then need to make post calls using Http Clients (like Spring RestTemplate) to post the POST body, soap based, to the endpoint address. This will make your calls faster but you have to code more in order to benefit.

Comment: Can you add some details? I went with your suggestion, but this is not enough info to follow along? Add some detail (example code may be), so that I can mark it as accepted