# Do WSDL needs to be active always even if we change the URL dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, soap, wsdl, oracle-fusion-middleware

I am trying to add a `service reference` in my `C#` project using a `WSDL` URL and trying to change the URL in run time by sending the URL value as an argument into the service constructor as mentioned in the following answer.

[How to change webservice url endpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490737/how-to-change-webservice-url-endpoint/29156864#29156864)

My doubt is that whether the WSDL URL I add in the project needs to be accessible always when the application is running?  Whether it will cause any error when the URL goes down or become not available.

Please let me know if you need any clarification on this query?

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't. You'll just need it if you have to update the reference by using the "Update Service Reference" menu option on the menu context when you right-click your service reference.